# How data is updated real time?

Tags: sql, sql-server, tableau-api

So I was wondering that if a table is in editing mode(say in SQL), it cannot be accessed or changed by some other user. But then how is that we see real time visualization in Tableau ?, how come we are seeing charts but they are being updated at the back end in real time. Technically it can't be changed or accessed.
I would like to understand how data is updated real time and at the same time we use those tables to see dynamic charts.

I tried searching internet over this, closest I came to HSQL, but I am not able to understand.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server provides transaction isolation levels to provide read consistency. These may use either locking or row versioning depending on the session transaction isolation level and database configuration.

The default transaction isolation level is `READ_COMMITTED` implemented with locking. In this case, read-only queries like those used for your Tableau visualization will happily select data unless the requested rows are currently being updated. The query will then wait until the transaction is committed and then proceed returning the latest data. Depending on the workload, the duration of blocking like this may be so small as to be transparent to the application. But in the case of large batch updates, the blocking duration can be significant. Note that SQL Server will use granular locks when possible rather than locking the entire table.

A DBA can change this behavior by turning on the database `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT` database option. This causes the `READ_COMMITTED` isolation level to use row versioning instead of locking to provide read consistency. With this option turned on, the Tableau queries will receive the before image of updated data instead of being blocked by an in-progress transaction. There is some additional overhead with row versioning so DBAs don't turn on the `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT` database option on indiscriminately. Turning on the option improve concurrency but at the cost of resource usage.

Comment: This makes sense, thank you for your inputs

Answer (score 1):

I was wondering if you are asking the opposite of what you are asking :)

Databases think of data as the unique truce and they will execute your commands on those data. **The data is not locked when you are seeing it on your screen**.
When you present the data, say in an application or even in Management studio (for SQL server) they query the DB on that specific time and show it to you and when you change something, they send an update command to the server. The data is not locked.

DBs have a locking process on tables that usually works when you have a time consuming command and you don't want any proccess reading the data while some of them are in invalid state. Lets say you are doing an update increasing col1 by 1. Now in the middle of the update if someone query on data and SQL returns the data some of them will be the updated value and some others will not which usually is not what you want.

However, there is a mode in SQL called "Single user mode" which disables all connections from all other users and doesn't let them connect letting the DBA to take care of the DB (usually when you have a big DB change).

Comment: This makes sense, thank you for your inputs